# Merging the data from 2 users of a dynamic pdf form into a single document

Tags: forms, pdf, livecycle-designer, merging-data

I developed a dynamic pdf form with livecycle designer es2, which is a list of products with associated characteristics.

I am wondering if there is a way for 2 users of the form to generate their subset of data (i.e. each would document the information relative to a subset of products) and import the data from one user into the form of the second user to combine both users entries?

I tried to export the data from one record and then import them in the second record but the result I obtained was that the data from the 2nd user were overwritten by the data from the 1st user.

Any idea?

Comment: Export both and look at the data. It's XML, it should be intuitive on how to combine them. Then you could crate a repeatable solution in code or XSL

Comment: I am trying to use

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am trying to use the xfa.host.import() function but something creates an error and I don't know what. I created a button to (1) save the existing data in an array, (2) import new data, (3) create new instance of the subform and (4) paste the data from the array in the added instances. But the script stops right after the import function. So if I import the data a first time in the form, I get the expected data. Then if I import other data, I get the new data but the old data are lost. If I run the script but cancel the import, then I get the data duplicated. So  what's wrong?

Comment: Can you examine the first form data and the second form data? Externally. And combine them by hand and them import?

Comment: Yes I was able to do that and that will be our back up solution if a better one can't be found. Thanks for your help.